# Use `inspect an element` tool to make global Javascript variable

Tags: google-chrome, firebug, development-environment, google-chrome-devtools

In the modern browsers (and Firefox + firebug) you can open up your developer tools and either go to the `HTML`/`Elements` tab, or you can `inspect an element` to get an interactive DOM display.

You can do heaps of useful stuff here, and one thing I need to do often is manipulate/interact with a particular element using Javascript (in the `console` tab).

What I've been doing is using the interactive DOM to add an id attribute like 'bob', then doing whatever I need to do in the console with `document.getElementById('bob')` (or `$('#bob')`).

Ideally what I'd like to do is right click on the element and select an option like `make JS variable` so in the `console` I can just use a variable called `bob`,
does anyone know of any such hidden feature/addon/faster method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use the `$0` variable in the devtools to get a DoM reference to the last element you selected in the `Elements` pane.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#0-4
[image: print screen]

<sub>**NB** This works in Firefox, too!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in XPath context menu as a shortcut. Here is the process:

- Right Click on an element from within the DOM Inspector tab
- Select `Copy XPath` from the context menu
- Paste selector into the console
- Enclose the selector in single quotes
- Enclose the selector in the [$x()](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#xpath) method of the console API
- Append the array index of the selector match
- Append the desired property/method reference

  ```
  $x('//*[@id="header"]')[0].innerText
  ```

Comment: hey Paul, leaving you with the upvote I'm going to move the tick over to the new answer because I want to emphasise that new viewers should use that technique. Just letting you know, thanks for your help!